# Idiomatic streams in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-async

In playing with Dart, particularly the `dart:io` library, I've found myself doing weird things with Streams to allow multiple listeners.

For example, I want to emulate the handler-stack pattern found in a number of Node libraries (like Connect & Express). To do so, I need to be able to set up multiple listeners on the request (and response), which means producing a broadcast stream from the request.

This cannot be the only thing I pass around becuase it does not maintain the properties of the request object (such as the response).

```dart
handleRequest (HttpRequest request) {
  var stream = request.asBroadcastStream();
  // pass stream *and* request to the handlers
}
```

An example handler, showing the problem, might look like this:

```dart
log (HttpRequest request, Stream stream) {
  DateTime start = new DateTime.now();
  stream.listen(null,
    onDone: () {
      DateTime finish = new DateTime.now();
      print("${request.method} ${request.uri} -> ${request.response.statusCode} ${finish.difference(start).inMilliseconds}ms");
    });
}
```

What's the idiomatic way of doing this kind of thing? I don't want to force Dart to conform to my JavaScriptish way.

Comment: Do you want the multiple listeners to work "in order"? That is, A then B then C?

Comment: For the Java peeps reading this, it sounds like you want to implement Filters. They intercept requests, potentially modify the request or do something (but not fully handle the request), and then potentially pass the request on. Is that accurate?

Comment: @SethLadd In order, yes. Filters sound good, but what about the logging example where a listener is required to know when the request/response is ended? There could be multiple examples of these.

Comment: I've just published 'Shelf', which is a very early attempt to provide features like Connect - https://github.com/kevmoo/shelf.dart - take a look

Answer (score 2):

The `asBroadcastStream()` method is one of the most abused methods of Streams. I have written an article on Streams, and I hope it will be published soon. In short: the lifetime of a single-subscription Stream is defined by its subscription, and `asBroadcastStream()` destroys the lifetime management of a Stream. It's a source for resource leaks.

If you want to inform other parts of your program of messages you get from a single-subscription stream it is probably the best to create a new BroadcastStream (independent from the single-subscription stream) where you post messages when they arrive from the single-subscription stream. If these need more information you should send it this way.

In other words: create a new `StreamController.broadcast` and share this one with interested parties. If you want, you can also extend Stream and provide more information this way. Keep the single-subscription stream for yourself and publish interesting information in the shared broadcast stream.

Single-subscription streams are designed to be consumed by one entity.

Edit: the article has been published [here](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/broadcast-streams/).

Comment: Thanks Florian. In the case described above however, I want to share the properties on the request object, so I'd still have to pass around the new broadcast stream and the request, or manually copy the properties over. It seems to me there's a 'Dart-y' way to do this, possibly without using a broadcast stream?

Comment: I asked our local IO expert and he didn't have any better suggestion.